# Ada: how to solve "Circular Unit Dependency"?

Tags: ada, circular-dependency, circular-reference

Suppose I have two records: *Person* and *Animal*. Each record is in a separate package.

Package persons:

```
with animals;
use animals;

package persons is 

    type person is record
     ...
     animalref: animalPOINTER;
     ...
    end record;

    type personPOINTER is access person;

end persons;
```

Package animals:

```
with persons;
use persons;

package animals is 
    type animal is record
     ...
     ownerref:  personPOINTER;
     ...
    end record;

    type animalPOINTER is access animal;

end animals;
```

I have Circular Unit Dependency here, and compiler produces fatal error.

Does anyone have a pattern to address such issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: If you search “[ada] circular unit dependency” you’ll find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31621183/40851).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need `limited with`, which was introduced to address exactly this problem. See the [Rationale for Ada 2005, section 4.2](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-4-2.html).

`Animals` and `Persons` are symmetric (my editor has adjusted the layout and casing; I’ve added one record component to each so the demo program, below, can print something):

```
limited with Animals;
package Persons is

   --  One of the few things you can do with an incomplete type, which
   --  is what Animals.Animal is in the limited view of Animals, is to
   --  declare an access to it.
   type AnimalPOINTER is access Animals.Animal;

   type Person is record
      Name : Character;
      Animalref : AnimalPOINTER;
   end record;

end Persons;

limited with Persons;
package Animals is

   type PersonPOINTER is access Persons.Person;

   type Animal is record
      Name : Character;
      Ownerref : PersonPOINTER;
   end record;

end Animals;
```

The demo program has the full view of `Animals` and `Persons`. This example is pretty clumsy; you may be able to organise things better by adding subprograms to `Animals` and `Persons`. Note that the *body* of `Animals` can (and must) `with Persons;` if it needs to use anything in `Persons`.

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Animals;
with Persons;
procedure Animals_And_Persons is
   A : Persons.animalPOINTER := new Animals.Animal;
   P : Animals.PersonPOINTER := new Persons.Person;
begin
   A.all := (Name => 'a', Ownerref => P);
   P.all := (Name => 'p', Animalref => A);
   Put_Line (P.Name & " owns " & P.Animalref.Name);
   Put_Line (A.Name & " is owned by " & A.Ownerref.Name);
end Animals_And_Persons;
```

which when compiled and run gives

```
$ ./animals_and_persons 
p owns a
a is owned by p
```